# Are these escape options for a Large creature correct?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, opportunity-attack

A Beast Master ranger is riding a Large size Dire Wolf which is surrounded by 3 Medium size enemies placed at 3 different sides (let's say, North, West, East). The only escape route is northward. In order to escape, the wolf can:

- Use the Disengage action and an Acrobatics check in order to pass the space occupied by the hostile creature
- Use the Disengage action, retreat 10 feet in order to take a run-up and perform a high-jump northward

Now, are these two options correct? In the second case, would the northward enemy get an opportunity attack on the jumping wolf if it does not use the Disengage action? Consider that it can jump 6 feet high.

Answer (score 1):

> you can move through a hostile creature's 
>   space only if the creature is at least two sizes larger or 
>   smaller than you. Remember that another creature’s 
>   space is difficult terrain for you.

The wolf **cannot** move through a hostile creature's space so your first option is N/A.

The would can jump over the creature if it can clear 5 feet so it is not in the same space. A normal wolf can only clear 4 feet without augmentation so your second option is N/A. However, f for some reason it **can** clear 6 feet then it doesn't provoke an opportunity attack if it took the disengage action.

However, the wolf can move north-west or north-east and go between the opponents and then head north.

Comment: Sorry, it was a Dire Wolf and not a Wolf, that is why it can clear 6 feet. I edited the question. However, I would like to know if the jump provokes an opportunity attack if the wolf does not use the Disengage action.

Comment: @firion That's a separate question.

Comment: Actually, Dale M already answered it since it was included in the original question, but I specified that I am interested in the case when the dire wolf does NOT use the disengage action

Comment: @firion What reason do you have to doubt that it would provoke an opportunity attack when not using Disengage? If the doubt is anything more complex than "I don't know, I was just checking", then it would seem that you have a more complex question about opportunity attacks, which could need a dedicated question to be answered properly.

Comment: Acrobatics specifically lists somersaulting over an enemy as an option for the skill.